# SQL (mysql) - SELECT distinct `products` FROM all PARENT USERS

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i just need to group products after order by ID, i think it's very often thing, but every time i have problem with there.

It's recursive nesting.

Table `products`

```
id
code
user_id
name
```

Data `products`

```
1 code1 1 product_user1_code1
2 code2 1 product_user1_code2
3 code3 1 product_user1_code3
4 code2 2 product_user2_code2
5 code1 3 product_user3_code1
```

Table `user_nest`

```
id
parent_id
delta_level
```

Data `user_nest`:

```
1 1 0
2 2 0
2 1 1
3 3 0
3 2 1
3 1 2
```

that means below user nesting:

- 1

  - 2

    - 3

===

- user have default products and can see it
- user can change products
- user can invite another user
- new user must see products have closest parent user changes
- new user can do same actions like user - see, change, invite

For given example i expect to get 3 rows:

product_user3_code1 (edited by me id:3)
product_user2_code2 (edited by my parent id:2)
product_user1_code3 (defined by admin id:1)

Can someone help?

Comment: provide your expected resultset

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Guys, so i think my task is very often task, sorry.
Ok, i just try explain again:

user have default products and can see it
user can change products.
user can invite another user.
new user must see products have parent user changes
new user can do same actions like user - see, change, invite

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT max(t1.id), t1.code, t1.user_id, t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.delta_level
FROM `user_nest` t1
INNER JOIN
`product` t2 ON t2.`user_id` = t1.`parent_id`
WHERE t1.`id` = 3
GROUP BY t1.code, t1.user_id, t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.delta_level
```

Though I have not tried this query but I think this will help you.

Comment: Sorry but no, even if fix the given code, it return 1 row, some like you just define MAX(id), we cannot use MAX(id) because level nesting is controlled by level property

Answer (score 0):

This variant becomes to solution... i have to test him a little bit more

```
SELECT
  t1.id
  , t1.parent_id
  , MIN(t1.level) min_level
  , t2.*
FROM
  user_nest t1
INNER JOIN
  product t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.parent_id
WHERE
  t1.id = 3
GROUP BY
  t2.code
```